# how to use var value name as function name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi guys can i use value as a function name in JavaScript? i have some functions with same name input values such as:

```
var ta = $('li.ramin.active').attr("id");
var act = $('input[name="'+ta+'_acceptdeny"]:checked').val();


act(Freq, meID);  // my question is
```

in this way i have error "Uncaught TypeError: act is not a function" yes i know act is not a function but i want to use var act value as function name!! so i need to know how i can do that? thanks to all

Comment: what's `Freq` and `meID`? That's not clear what exactly you're asking

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string

Comment: You *can* do that, but you **probably shouldn't**. I'd advise you to explain why you want to do that and maybe get an answer for a better design. Also, you could benefit from studying JavaScript more thoroughly as it looks you lack some basic understanding (by the terms you use).

Comment: function custom values such as act(1, 2)

Comment: i have to use such way because i have multiple tabs and i must use separate functions for each tabs and this is easy way to do

Comment: Any time you find yourself needing to get a variable or function name from  a string, you probably should be using an object to map names to values. You can make an object whose values are functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window[act](Freq, meId)`

Thanks [Justin Niessner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84651/justin-niessner) for pointing out this will only work if `act` is defined in the global scope. You could use `eval`, however, this is generally considered to be very unsafe.

Comment: That depends on how the function is defined. This may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you from re-declaring act as a function, you would just lose all references to the initially declared act from the point onward.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the value as a function name, put the functions into an object, and use the value as the key to the object.

```
var myFunctions = {
    'func1': function() { .... },
    'func2': function() { .... },
    // and so on
};

var ta = $('li.ramin.active').attr("id");
var act = $('input[name="'+ta+'_acceptdeny"]:checked').val();

myFunctions[act](Freq, meID);
```

This is better because you can't accidentally call a function that was not intended to be used by the application, it can only call functions in the `myFunctions` object.